# What is the quotient field of a localization of a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> If $R$ is an integral domain, $K=\text{Frac}(R)$ and $S$ is a multiplicative subset of $R$ then is $K$ also the quotient field of $R_S$?

I've tried showing that the ring map $K \to \text{Frac}(R_S)$ given by $a/b\mapsto \frac{a/1}{b/1}$ is onto but this looks tricky. Maybe this is not possible.

Is there anyone who can help me with this one?

Comment: $R\subset R_S\subset K$, and the field of fractions of an integral domain is the *smallest* field containing it.

Comment: Yes that definitely does it. Would you know if my approach also works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may find the following helpful.

Let $R$ be a ring and $T, S$ multiplicative subsets such that $S \subset T$.
Then it is true that $(R_{S})_{\bar{T}} \cong R_T$, where $\bar{T}$ is the image
of $T$ under the canonical homomorphism $R \rightarrow R_S$. (This relation
is really saying that if you make the elements of $S$ units (this is $R_S$)
and then in $R_S$ you make the elements of $\bar{T}$ units, then this is the 
same as making directly the elements of $T$ units in $R$, i.e. the intermediate
step of inverting the elements of the smaller set $S$ does not play a role.)

Now note that the field of fractions of an integral domain $R$ is its localization
at the prime ideal $0$, i.e. $K = R_0$. Since $R_S$ is an integral domain, its 
field of fractions is $(R_S)_{\bar{0}}$. Since $S \subset R-0$ we have that
$(R_S)_{\bar{0}} \cong R_0 = K$.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I think I need more reputation points to vote up- I'll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Gwan: Ah ok, no problem :)